# Using Jsoup to login into page

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup to login into a page, but this does not seem to be working. The page is https://homestead.schoolloop.com/portal/login.

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://homestead.schoolloop.com/portal/login")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Map<String, String> cookies = loginForm.cookies();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("login_name", "myusername");
    params.put("password", "mypassword");
    params.put("redirect", "");
    params.put("forward", "");
    params.put("login_form_reverse", "");
    params.put("form_data_id", "19892698508822030");
    params.put("sort", "");
    params.put("reverse", "");
    params.put("login_form_sort", "");
    params.put("event_override", "");
    params.put("login_form_filter", "");
    params.put("login_form_letter", "");
    params.put("return_url", "1523778628268");
    params.put("login_form_page_index", "");
    params.put("login_form_page_item_count", "");

    String strActionURL = "https://homestead.schoolloop.com/portal/login?etarget=login_form";

    Response responsePostLogin = Jsoup.connect(strActionURL) 
            //referrer will be the login page's URL
            .referrer("https://homestead.schoolloop.com/portal/login")
            //user agent
            //connect and read time out
            .timeout(10 * 1000)
            //post parameters
            .data(params)
            //cookies received from login page
            .cookies(cookies)
            //many websites redirects the user after login, so follow them
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();

    System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + responsePostLogin.statusCode());

    Document document = responsePostLogin.parse();
```

Sorry for the very scattered code, but I was mixing and matching responses online in the attempt to get it to work. In its current state, when I print out the document, it returns the HTML of hhs.fuhsd.org rather than the logged in portal. Am I missing something very basic? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I did not look into details, but very likely you need to first access the login page and gather the session cookies. Then send these cookies along in the parameters of the login post request.

Comment: @luksch I believe I did this through "Map<String, String> cookies = loginForm.cookies();" and then passing it with ".cookies(cookies)". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: oh... have overlooked that. Yes, that should indeed do the trick. It might be that you are held back by cloudflare though. I was asked if I was a robot before I could see the login site...

Comment: @luksch Is there anyway past cloudfare? Or can I just not access it using jsoup?

Comment: not that I know of, sorry dude :(